# sshd_config adding a delay between login attempts?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

Is there a configuration for this without installing 3rd party software?

Answer (score 6):

You can do rate-limiting easily with iptables, and this can be done without giving the machine a full firewall.

The code is

```
# rate-limit connections to sshd
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m recent --name sshattack --set
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -m recent --name sshattack --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 -j LOG --log-prefix 'SSH REJECT: '
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -m recent --name sshattack --rcheck --seconds 60 --hitcount 3 -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

which will only allow two connections from any given IP address, in a rolling 60-second window.  You will need to be careful to put these rules in the right place in your INPUT chain.

See [my writeup](http://www.teaparty.net/technotes/ssh-rate-limiting.html) for more information, if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

No, not that I know of. There is no such thing with openssh.

What you have is

```
MaxStartups
    Specifies the maximum number of concurrent unauthenticated connections 
    to the SSH daemon.  Additional connections will be dropped until authentication 
    succeeds or the LoginGraceTime expires for a connection. The default is 10.
```

But I don't think this is what you were looking for.