# how to configure fail login delay using iptables

Tags: linux, ssh, iptables

Like in Subject, I need to set particular delay i.e. when wrong password is provided. I can't use PAM. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/238163/sshd-config-adding-a-delay-between-login-attempts?answertab=votes#tab-top) is your answer, using iptables but check by the way if you cannot do what you're looking for in /etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: That is not what I would like to do, I need provide delay between password prompts in case of authentication failure. Your solluton allow two connections from any given IP address, in a rolling 60-second window but doesn't provide any delay.

Comment: Are you looking for a delayed prompt between login attempts ? Because I don't think it's gonna be possible with iptables, but only with PAM or another 3rd party software. You'll be able to only delay the connection attempts with iptables. By changing the rules like this: "--seconds 15 --hitcount 2", it will allow one connection attempt every 15 seconds, but the client has to type his command again.